# How can I create Log4j 2 appender connected with jTextPane?

Tags: jtextpane, appender, log4j2

I'm currently trying to make `Log4j 2` log into a `JTextPane`. It should act like a STDERR or STDOUT in Netbeans IDE console (incl. text style - color).

I know that I need to create an *appender* and connect it with `JTextPane`, however I don't know how do it using `Log4j 2`.

Do you have any suggestions?

I appreciate your help,
marty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this for Logback (with plain text only). The basic things you need to do are:

- Implement your own Appender to receive the log events. Log4j 2 provides [`AbstractAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/AbstractAppender.html), which will give you the baseline functionality.
- Use an appropriate `Layout` to format the log event (will depend what type of [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) you're using for your `JTextPane`.
- Append the formatted text to the underlying `Document` for the `JTextPane`.

A couple of other points:

- Things will be simpler if you log plain text only, in which case you should use a `JTextArea`.
- Presumably you will want to cap the amount of text in the `Document`. You can do this by checking the length on each append and cutting out the first X% using `Document.remove` when it exceeds the maximum length.
- If you have frequent log operations, you should limit the frequency at which you append to the document, and buffer the changes in between to reduce the swing update/repaint overhead. I typically use 3 Hz. This is also advisable when you have multiple log producer threads because although the `Document.insertString` method is thread-safe, it obtains a lock on the document before performing the update and can result in quite a bit of contention.

I'd highly recommend referencing the documentation for this. I've never used Log4j 2, but the documentation looks quite straight forward. Similarly, the "Using Text Components" section of the Java Tutorials provides everything you need to know about the Swing side. Unfortunately I can't provide additional links here.